# PHP Human date range/duration format

Tags: php, date, format

PHP is so well made that I am wondering if there is a function for what I need.

For events that last more than one day, the human way to format it is complex.

Exemples...

Event one: from 2015-04-20 to 2015-04-22 could be formatted for humans like this: April 20-22 2015

Event two: from 2015-04-01 to 2015-05-31 Humans -> April-May 2015

Event three: from 2015-04-30 to 2015-05-02 Humans -> April 30 to May 2 2015

In short, never repeat what doesn't needs to be repeated. Link with "-" as much as possible.

It will have to be localized and the format could change depending of the local. For exemple, US folks like MonthName DayNumber Year but French like DayNumber  MonthName Year.

I was planning on programming such formatting, but I was wondering if it already existed :)

Comment: I don't think you can do such a thing without a little work. The native DateTime class will do most of the job reading the dates and formatting them for you, though!

Comment: The date format seems quite random actually. People don't necessarily know that "April-May 2015" means exactly 1 April to 31 May. Why not be more specific and use the same format for all the intervals.

Comment: You think! Humans fill the blanks you know. They know pretty well that the event will be in April and May. Humans also likes short and intuitive formats. A format like 2015-04-01 to 2015-05-31 is long and much harder to understand and evaluate than April-May 2015. IMHO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works...

```
function humanDateRanges($start, $end){
    $startTime=strtotime($start);
    $endTime=strtotime($end);

    if(date('Y',$startTime)!=date('Y',$endTime)){
        echo date('F j, Y',$startTime) . " to " . date('F j, Y',$endTime);
    }else{
        if((date('j',$startTime)==1)&&(date('j',$endTime)==date('t',$endTime))){
            echo date('F',$startTime) . " to " . date('F, Y',$endTime);
        }else{
            if(date('m',$startTime)!=date('m',$endTime)){
                echo date('F j',$startTime) . " to " . date('F j, Y',$endTime);
            }else{
                echo date('F j',$startTime) . " to " . date('j, Y',$endTime);
            }
        }
    }
}

humanDateRanges("2015-04-20", "2015-04-22");
//April 20 to 22, 2015
humanDateRanges("2015-04-01", "2015-05-31");
//April to May, 2015
humanDateRanges("2015-04-30", "2015-05-02");
//April 30 to May 2, 2015
humanDateRanges("2014-05-02", "2015-05-02");
//May 2, 2014 to May 2, 2015
```

But I do think in some situations, even human beings need to be told that April-May will begin the 1st and end the 31st.

Comment: +1 Awesome! You could instead use the "n" for month comparison. Also I need to figure a way to localize this :)

Comment: to localize it, replace all of the date() functions with strftime(), the formatting options are a little different with `%Y` for year instead of just `Y` but it's the same, and you can set the locale at the top of the function.  Just pass it in as another variable and set it.  You should also probably be returning the results, not echoing them, I think it would be more useful that way, this was just a quick stab at it. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this: I've written a small library that tries to solve this problem in a way that also works with internationalization:

https://github.com/flack/ranger

It should provide a reasonable default for ltr languages (and rtl support shouldn't be too hard to add)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution trying to target every possible locale.
There is definitely still room for improvement.
Have a look at this demo: https://www.tehplayground.com/JIrjclNy3jEoVrTJ

```php
function format_dateRange($from, $to, $options=[]){
    if (!is_numeric($from)) $from = strtotime($from);
    if (!is_numeric($to)) $to = strtotime($to);

    $fromArr = explode('.',date('Y.n.j', $from));
    $toArr   = explode('.',date('Y.n.j', $to));

    $sameYear  = $fromArr[0] === $toArr[0];
    $sameMonth = $sameYear && $fromArr[1] === $toArr[1];
    $sameDay   = $sameMonth && $fromArr[2] === $toArr[2];


    $locale = $options['locale'] ?? setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
    $dateType = $options['dateType'] ?? \IntlDateFormatter::LONG;
    $timeType = $options['timeType'] ?? \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;
    $ignoreTime = $timeType === 'none' || ($timeType === 'optional' && !$sameDay);

    if ($timeType === 'optional') {
        $timeType = $sameDay ? \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT : \IntlDateFormatter::NONE;
    }

    $startFormatter = new \IntlDateFormatter($locale,$dateType,$timeType,null);
    $pattern = $startFormatter->getPattern();

    $timeSeparator = $options['timeSeparator'] ?? ' – '; 
    $daySeparator  = $options['daySeparator'] ?? ' – ';
    $dateSeparator = $options['dateSeparator'] ?? ' – ';

    if ($timeType === \IntlDateFormatter::NONE) {
        if ($sameMonth) { // include day-range
            preg_match("/(?<!['])dd?\.?/", $pattern, $matches);
            $partPattern = trim($matches[0]);
            $endFormatter = new \IntlDateFormatter($locale,$dateType,$timeType,null);
            $endFormatter->setPattern($partPattern);
            $endPart = $endFormatter->getPattern();
            $preg = "/".preg_quote($partPattern)."(?!e)/"; 
            $pattern = preg_replace($preg, $partPattern."'".$daySeparator.($endFormatter->format($to))."'", $pattern); 
        } else if ($sameYear) { // include day-month-range
            preg_match('/(d+.+M+|M+.+d+(?!\'))/', $pattern, $matches);
            $partPattern = $matches[0];
            $endFormatter = new \IntlDateFormatter($locale,$dateType,$timeType,null);
            $endFormatter->setPattern($partPattern);
            $endPart = $endFormatter->getPattern();
            $pattern = str_replace($partPattern, $partPattern."'".$daySeparator.($endFormatter->format($to))."'", $pattern);
        }
        // else just the pattern?
    } else {
        if ($sameDay) { // incluce time-range
            $endFormatter = new \IntlDateFormatter($locale,\IntlDateFormatter::NONE,$timeType,null);
            $endPart = $endFormatter->getPattern();
            $pattern = str_replace($endPart, $endPart."'".$timeSeparator.($endFormatter->format($to))."'", $pattern);
        } else { // append end-date
            $endFormatter = new \IntlDateFormatter($locale,$dateType,$timeType,null);
            $pattern .= "'".$dateSeparator.$endFormatter->format($to)."'";
        }
    }

    $startFormatter->setPattern($pattern);
    $str = $startFormatter->format($from);
    return $str;
}

$locales = ['af-ZA','am-ET','ar-AE','ar-BH','ar-DZ','ar-EG','ar-IQ','ar-JO','ar-KW','ar-LB','ar-LY','ar-MA','arn-CL','ar-OM','ar-QA','ar-SA','ar-SY','ar-TN','ar-YE','as-IN','az-Cyrl-AZ','az-Latn-AZ','ba-RU','be-BY','bg-BG','bn-BD','bn-IN','bo-CN','br-FR','bs-Cyrl-BA','bs-Latn-BA','ca-ES','co-FR','cs-CZ','cy-GB','da-DK','de-AT','de-CH','de-DE','de-LI','de-LU','dsb-DE','dv-MV','el-GR','en-029','en-AU','en-BZ','en-CA','en-GB','en-IE','en-IN','en-JM','en-MY','en-NZ','en-PH','en-SG','en-TT','en-US','en-ZA','en-ZW','es-AR','es-BO','es-CL','es-CO','es-CR','es-DO','es-EC','es-ES','es-GT','es-HN','es-MX','es-NI','es-PA','es-PE','es-PR','es-PY','es-SV','es-US','es-UY','es-VE','et-EE','eu-ES','fa-IR','fi-FI','fil-PH','fo-FO','fr-BE','fr-CA','fr-CH','fr-FR','fr-LU','fr-MC','fy-NL','ga-IE','gd-GB','gl-ES','gsw-FR','gu-IN','ha-Latn-NG','he-IL','hi-IN','hr-BA','hr-HR','hsb-DE','hu-HU','hy-AM','id-ID','ig-NG','ii-CN','is-IS','it-CH','it-IT','iu-Cans-CA','iu-Latn-CA','ja-JP','ka-GE','kk-KZ','kl-GL','km-KH','kn-IN','kok-IN','ko-KR','ky-KG','lb-LU','lo-LA','lt-LT','lv-LV','mi-NZ','mk-MK','ml-IN','mn-MN','mn-Mong-CN','moh-CA','mr-IN','ms-BN','ms-MY','mt-MT','nb-NO','ne-NP','nl-BE','nl-NL','nn-NO','nso-ZA','oc-FR','or-IN','pa-IN','pl-PL','prs-AF','ps-AF','pt-BR','pt-PT','qut-GT','quz-BO','quz-EC','quz-PE','rm-CH','ro-RO','ru-RU','rw-RW','sah-RU','sa-IN','se-FI','se-NO','se-SE','si-LK','sk-SK','sl-SI','sma-NO','sma-SE','smj-NO','smj-SE','smn-FI','sms-FI','sq-AL','sr-Cyrl-BA','sr-Cyrl-CS','sr-Cyrl-ME','sr-Cyrl-RS','sr-Latn-BA','sr-Latn-CS','sr-Latn-ME','sr-Latn-RS','sv-FI','sv-SE','sw-KE','syr-SY','ta-IN','te-IN','tg-Cyrl-TJ','th-TH','tk-TM','tn-ZA','tr-TR','tt-RU','tzm-Latn-DZ','ug-CN','uk-UA','ur-PK','uz-Cyrl-UZ','uz-Latn-UZ','vi-VN','wo-SN','xh-ZA','yo-NG','zh-CN','zh-HK','zh-MO','zh-SG','zh-TW','zu-ZA'];
$variants = [];
foreach ($locales as $locale) {
    $variant = format_dateRange(time(), time()+60*5, ['locale' => $locale, 'timeType' => 'optional']);
    $variants[$variant] = [
        'locale' => $locale,
        'sameday' => $variant,
        'samemonth' => format_dateRange(time()-60*60*13, time()+60*60*13, ['locale' => $locale, 'timeType' => 'optional']),
        'sameyear' => format_dateRange(time()-60*60*24*16, time()+60*60*24*16, ['locale' => $locale, 'timeType' => 'optional']),
    ];
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($variants as $variant => $row) {
    echo 
    '<tr>'.
        '<td>'.$row['locale'].
        '<td>'.$row['sameday'].
        '<td>'.$row['samemonth'].
        '<td>'.$row['sameyear'];
}
echo '</table>';
```