# Abbreviating two dates by removing duplicate parts using php

Tags: php, string, date

Is there a function or a shorthand to write out two dates without repeating the unnecessary information?

e.g, if I print out 2 dates through the date function, such as

> 4th October 2018 - 12th October 2018

Is there any way to do the exclude the duplicate information? In this instance, what I'd want it to write out is

> 4th - 12th October 2018

Because the month and year are repeated, but I'm not asking to just write out the first date using only the day operator. So if it's possible to have it understand if it needs to write out the month too

e.g,

> 29th October 2018 - 3rd November 2018

**becomes**

> 29th October - 3rd November 2018

Because the day and month are different, but not the year.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Split the dates into parts, check if the year part matches and remove it from the first date if so. Check if the month part matches and remove that too if needed. Then output what's left.

Comment: Utilizing Google search produced a result from Stack Exchange (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78295/formatting-a-date-range-with-shortening-if-the-interval-falls-entirely-within-a)

Comment: A custom function has to write. [Ref1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78295/formatting-a-date-range-with-shortening-if-the-interval-falls-entirely-within-a) , [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976026/php-human-date-range-duration-format)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, ah, that's the kind of thing I was looking for, I wasn't sure what to search for, most of the time it returned results for getting the actual difference between dates instead of a formatting code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split dates using `explode()` and loop through return array using `for`. In loop check if every item of dates is same remove it from array. After loop use `implode()` to converting array to string.

```
$date = "29th October 2018";
$date2 ="3rd November 2018";
$exp = explode(" ", $date);
$exp2 = explode(" ", $date2);

for($i=sizeof($exp)-1; $i>0; $i--)
    if ($exp[$i] == $exp2[$i])
        unset($exp[$i]);   

$newDate = implode(" ", $exp)." - ".implode(" ", $exp2);
// 29th October - 3rd November 2018
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/43Xsg)

Comment: I like this method, it's nice and simple and it'll just take the text strings and cut out the duplicates.